# Is it possible that converting inner join select result to nested list JSON?

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I am developing an API controller with Spring.

I have two tables and they are one-to-many relationships.
One video can have multiple products.

[image]

I can select the video and product information with join query.
The select result is like below:

[image]

The JSON What I would like to return is below:

```
{
"videos": [{
    "video_id": "V0001",
    "video_nm": "Video001",
    "description": "Some text",
    "thumbnail": "path/img/aaa.jpg",
    "reg_dt": "11-30-2019",
    "products": [{
        "product_id": "P0001",
        "product_nm": "Product001",
        "description": "Some text",
        "info_url": "http://product.com"
    }, ...]
}, ...]
}
```

Is it possible to create the above JSON with the query result? Or should I change the JSON format?

Comment: It is certainly possible to convert your result set to this JSON inside your Java application.  As a side note, it might even be possible to do this in MySQL itself, if you are using a recent version.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you for the comments. Could you tell me what version of MySQL you are using?

Comment: A good reply to the above comment would have been to tell Tim what version of MySQL you are using

Comment: BTW I don't recommend doing this in MySQL (maybe in Postgres).  You need to write an object mapper in your Java code which can convert the result set to JSON.  It's not that difficult; poke around here and you'll find something quickly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To format the JSON in MySQL, you need to use the [JSON_OBJECT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object) function and the [JSON_ARRAYAGG()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) functions.

Something like the following — but I have not tested it.

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('videos', JSON_ARRAYAGG(vid_subquery.video)) AS videos
FROM (
  SELECT
    JSON_OBJECT(
      'video_id', v.video_id,
      'video_nm', v.video_nm,
      'description', v.description,
      'thumbnail', v.thumbnail,
      'reg_dt', v.reg_dt,
      'products', JSON_ARRAYAGG(
        JSON_OBJECT(
          'product_id', p.product_id,
          'product_nm', p.product_nm,
          'description', p.description,
          'info_url', p.info_url
        )
      )
    ) AS video
  FROM video AS v
  LEFT OUTER JOIN product AS p ON p.video_id = v.video_id
  GROUP BY v.video_id
) AS vid_subquery
```

If that seems too difficult, then you should follow the advice in the comments and write a Java mapper to do it.